# How do I tail Windows 10 Update Log

Tags: windows-10, powershell, tail, automatic-update

I have a following batch file that runs on startup

```
wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow
start /min C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log
```

But now in Windows 10 log file simply has the following

> Windows Update logs are now generated using ETW (Event Tracing for Windows).
>   Please run the Get-WindowsUpdateLog PowerShell command to convert ETW traces into a readable WindowsUpdate.log.

so I ran the command in powershell > `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`
and it converted the logs to a .log file and saved it on my desktop

It's a static file so defeats the purpose of me tailing it while it's running updates.

### Questions

How do I tail Windows 10 Update Log or it's not possible anymore?

### Problem X

I have 200+ VMs that i don't power on all the time. So i am working on a batch file that does "windows update" on Login, after the update now command i have it open the log file so i can keep an eye on it where we stand

ultimate goal is to act based on some entries in the log file and make decisions like reboot shutdown etc right away rather than prompting the user or waiting. so if there are more pending updates reboot and then install the remaining, on second attempt shutdown when no more updates

Comment: You can append data to an existing file using PowerShell.  You should try doing that.

Comment: which issue do you want to solve (xy problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: updated the Question with Problem X